# Loading 39567865 unsigned chars into RAM: Valid approach?

Tags: c++, optimization, storage

I am working on a C++ project, and I need to quickly access byte values.
I have experimented a lot with memory-mapped files, smart ordering of the data so that only little has to be read, etc.
I just could not get it to work fast enough reliable. There are always situations where the disk access and seeking in the file seems to be the bottle neck.

I was now thinking about loading the entire byte data (unsigned chars) into RAM.
However, it is 39567865 unsigned chars. It works on my computer, but I would like it to work on all computers.

Can anybody tell me if my approach is crazy or not? In other words: It is valid for a common software (not some scientific approach that is run on a super computer) to load such an amount of data into RAM to have it accessible quickly?

Comment: That is ~37.7 Mb, I don't think there are PCs today that will not be able to store that much memory on the RAM :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chars are 1 byte wide, so

```
39567865 / 1024 = 38,640 kb
```

This is about 37.7 Mb. You'll be fine, unless you plan to work on embedded machines that have very little RAM. For reference: The machine you are working on most likely has 4-8 Gb of RAM, your memory consumption is about 0.4%-0.8% of that.

Answer (score 1):

On today's usual Win32( or win64) machines loading up a 100M file into memory is completely fair, even preferred to alternatives.

The general answer depends on what system requirements you set, and what is the usual use pattern of the program, if it's launched in dozens of copies within seconds, some other way might be considered.